# Problems with pulling OneDrive/SharePoint Permissions

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, graph, onedrive

I am currently writing a script in nodejs to pull all DriveItems from the MS Graph API, the idea is to grab the permissions of each DriveItem so that a record can be kept and presented to the user. Our authentication with Graph is app based.

I am running asynchronous requests to MS graph which obviously results in a lot of simultaneous requests. After a few seconds of executing the script, MS graph starts returning the following errors from the endpoint and doesn't seem to recover. The status codes are a 500 internal server error, 504 gateway timeout, and 404 not found.

The number of errors returned isn't always the same; one request returns 856 failed requests, another returns 900.

Here are the different responses received from endpoints which represent true drives and driveitems:

Endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/(drive_id)/items/(driveitem_id)/permissions

500 Internal server error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-2146232060, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "794863b8-bbf1-4866-9604-f8fcec4afabe",
      "date": "2016-11-18T05:41:35"
    }
  }
}
```

504 Gateway timeout:

```
{ 
  "error": { 
    "code": "UnknownError", 
    "message": "", 
    "innerError": { 
      "request-id": "e91c3037-10b6-4523-88d3-7fc31107b719", 
      "date": "2016-11-18T05:46:21" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

404 Not found error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b9a8286d-ce8c-4353-b8f0-818fe0f609ea",
      "date": "2016-11-18T05:41:35"
    }
  } 
}
```

This errors occur for a period of time and then everything seems to work fine again.

I can confirm that these endpoints work fine when I use postman to get an individual endpoint and the same token as the script - it returns valid data. Also if I make the script synchronous, it works fine but this is not an acceptable solution as it is far too slow to process the thousands of files I am dealing with.

The only thing I can think of that would be a problem is the sheer amount of simultaneous requests happening? However I am not receiving a 429 too many requests error back from msgraph before this starts to happen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that you are running into issues with graph api. It seems like the database was overloaded, and started running slow, which is why you were seeing the 504s. SharePoint did return a 200 after a while for these requests but since graph times out after 10 seconds, you saw a 504.
For the 500s, again this is database-overload related. I have escalated the issue to our engineers who are working to fix it. Thanks for reporting the issue.

Comment: Hi Kashif thanks for the follow up, glad to hear it wasn't me doing something wrong! Are you please able to notify me once this issue has been resolved?

I'm currently limiting the amount of concurrent async API calls to mitigate this issue and would love to unleash the full potential of my app!

Comment: Everything should be back to normal now. Let us know if it's not!

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for the help!